# EF Core: The multi-part identifier \"m.Added\" could not be bound

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to migrate from EF 6 to EF Core.

I have this Linq to SQL query which returns daily top photo:

```
var model = db.Photos
    .Where(m => m.Added <= startDate && m.Active == true)
    .GroupBy(m => new { Year = m.Added.Year, Month = m.Added.Month, Day = m.Added.Day })
    .Select(m => m.FirstOrDefault())
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Added)
    .ThenBy(m => m.Rates.Sum(r => r.Points))
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

but same code on EF Core returns error:

> **Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider:** No column name was specified for column 1 of 'm2'. No column name was specified for column 2 of 'm2'. No column name was specified for column 3 of 'm2'. The multi-part identifier "m.Added" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "m.Added" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "m.Added" could not be bound.

how can i translate this to EF Core?

Comment: You shouldn't need a "translation". It should just work -- it's more likely that this is a bug in EF core. Query building is still under construction (https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/features.html).

Comment: tnx, any ideea how can i get this to work? maybe some workaround until EF team add this?

Comment: Yeah, workaround. Try to get the data in multiple simpler queries.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with a very simple expression:

```
var dates = items.Select(item => item.DateTime).Distinct();
// the multi-part identifier item.DateTime could not be bound
```

I got around this by creating and passing the equivalent function rather than an expression:

```
function DateTime GetItemDate(Item item)
{
    return item.DateTime;
}

var dates = items.Select(GetItemDate).Distinct();
```

As it's a workaround I would have preferred to post this to the comment discussion but I don't have the rep :/